# How should I set the ToolTip.AutoPopDelay property within the XAML for a button?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip

I create a button in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="RectangleButton" 
            Margin="0" 
            Width="{Binding LengthInPixels}" 
            Height="{Binding Height, Mode=OneWay}" 
            BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColor, Mode=OneWay}" 
            BorderThickness="0.2" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Background="{Binding BackgroundColor, Mode=OneTime}"
            ToolTip="{Binding MouseoverText, Mode=OneTime}"/>
</Grid>
```

Is it possible to set the ToolTip.AutoPopDelay (or whichever property lengthens the duration that the tooltip is visible on the screen) within the XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.initialshowdelay.aspx).

```
<Button ToolTip="{Binding MouseoverText, Mode=OneTime}"
        ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="1000" />
```

**Edit**

It turns out that you are looking for the [ToolTipService.ShowDuration Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showduration.aspx) and you will find still more properties in [ToolTipService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336408.aspx) to customize the `ToolTip`.

Comment: Thanks LPL. It looks like this may only be a winforms not a WPF thing, but I'd like to increase the length of time that the tooltip is on screen

Comment: This is the [ToolTipService.ShowDuration Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showduration.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - I'll edit the question to make it easier to spot the property, can you edit the answer?

Answer (score 2):

There's no such property in WPF. Maybe you mean [`ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.initialshowdelay.aspx)?

Comment: Snap! Thanks HighCore. It looks like this may only be a winforms not a WPF thing, but I'd like to increase the length of time that the tooltip is on screen